# Find a formula for AX=b

Tags: linear-algebra

If A is an mxn matrix, then for each $ \boldsymbol{b}\in \mathbf{C}(A) $, there is a unique $\boldsymbol{x }\in \boldsymbol{R}(A) $with Ax=b. In each case, give a formula for that X.

B)$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1&1 \\ 0& 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$

The answer to part b is suppose to be

$\begin{bmatrix} 1/3b_1 \\ 1/3b_1 +1/2b_2 \\ 1/3b_1-1/2b_2\end{bmatrix}$

But I can't seem to get this. I was using this problem to try and solve another problem of this type. However, I don't understand B) so could someone explain/show how their getting to this answer.

Comment: What have you done so far? If you post your solution we can see where you went wrong.

Comment: What is $R(A)$?

Comment: I haven't done much because I'm thinking I'm doing it wrong right from the start because.... I set it up like $x_1+x_2=b_1$ and $x_2-x_3=b_2$ but I stop here because I already see that I'm not going to have an answer with 3 rows since I only have two right now.

Comment: Start by finding a basis for $R(A)$. Then you can see what form $\mathbf x$ must take.